# C - Hash Table Clearing Advice

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, free

I am quite new to hash tables and on one of my assignments I need to clear the hash table of all memory. The following code works with no errors in Valgrind but I was wondering if maybe there is an easier way to clear the memory. Can anyone give me some advice on where I might be making this harder than necessary?

```
for (int u = 0; u < N; u++)
{
    if (hashtable[u] != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = hashtable[u];
        node *temp2 = temp;
        do
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            free(temp2);
            temp2 = temp;
        } while (temp != NULL);
        hashtable[u] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks perfect to me. The inner loop is the standard way to clear a linked list.

Comment: If the nodes had pointers to dynamic memory for the keys or values, you'd need to free them as well. But valgrind would have complained if you missed that, so I assume they don't.

Comment: More generally, questions about coding style of working programs are usually more appropriate at [codereview.se].

Comment: @ KyleStacksALot Although your method works, it can be improved slightly. So I agree that you should repost on Code Review.

Comment: You could move `node *temp2 = node;` to the top of the `do … while` loop and then drop the `temp2 = temp;` assignment at the end of the loop.  This improves locality of reference.  The compiler will manage creating the variable so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: You can reduce the number of lines using for loop: ```node * temp, * next;
for (temp = hashtable[u]; temp != NULL; temp = next)
    {
        next = temp->next;
        free (temp);
    }
hashtable[u] = NULL;```